# Nginx showing 404 instead of php page

Tags: php, nginx

I have nginx installed and if I go to uberdrivingparttime.app/ I get the usual "Welcome to nginx!" screen.  I put an index.php in the folder with phpinfo(); and when I go to uberdrivingparttime.app/index.php, I get a 404!  Here is my server blcok from config.  Hopefully someone knows what's up!

```
server {
    listen   80;
    server_name www.uberdrivingparttime.com uberdrivingparttime.com;
    access_log /srv/www/uberdrivingparttime.com/logs/access.log;
    error_log /srv/www/uberdrivingparttime.com/logs/error.log;

    location / {
        root   /srv/www/uberdrivingparttime.com/public_html;
        index  index.html index.htm index.php;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /srv/www/uberdrivingparttime.com/public_html$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am a tired, stupid, idiot.

So, everything is good here except for the fact that in /etc/hosts I have .app.  The directory where the files are located are .com!  Switching the server line to .app fixed everything.

Wow.